# Adding GA4 connection to AWS AppFlow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, amazon-appflow

I am trying to add an AppFlow connection to an existing GA4 account, GA4 is already up and running and even pushing data to BigQuery.

However, when I try to create the connection in Appflow to start a flow from GA4 to Redshift. I get this error message

```
An error occured while creating the connection ga4.
Error authenticating to connector: Failed to validate Connection while attempting "ValidateCredentials with CustomConnector" with connector failure The request failed because the service Source Google Analytics 4 returned the following error: Details: Google Analytics 4 returned error message - Request failed with Status Code: 403, Error Reason: Forbidden. (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Client; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
```

[image]

I have followed this documentation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/connectors-google-analytics-4.html

I was able to create a GA UA connection, but it used a slightly different OAuth Configuration.

My GCP App is set to Production and is External, my Google Analytics API is enabled and the OAuth Web Application creds are created, and the `Authorized redirect URIs` is set to `https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/appflow/oauth` as suggested by the documentation.

When I add the clientID and clientSecret to AppFlow's connection and click connect, I get a google login pop up prompt, and when I login in it asks me to allow amazon.com to access my data and pull data etc, which I do allow, then the pop up disappears and the above error pops up in AWS.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this issue and received this response from Amazon - after also enabling GA Admin API the connection worked

I would like to inform you that the user has to enable access to "Google Analytics API" as well as "Google Analytics ADMIN API" for successful connection through GA4 connector.

Therefore, I kindly request you to verify and enable both API's mentioned above if not done already.

I understand that the AWS documentation to setup GA4 with AppFlow only mentions enabling the "Google Analytics API" and not the "Google Analytics Admin API". Hence I will ask the internal team to get it updated. I apologize for the inconvenience you faced due to this issue.